# diagonalizable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-groups

The following is an exercise from Humphrey's *Linear Algebraic Groups* (page 108):

> Let $G$ be an algebraic group, $ \displaystyle H= \cap_{ \chi \in X
>  (G)} \ker ( \chi) $. Prove that:
>
> (a) $H$ is a closed, normal subgroup
>
> (b) $G/H$ is diagonalizable
>
> (c) $X(G) \cong X(G/H)$
>
> (d) Describe $X(GL_n(K))$

For (a): $H$ is closed (normal) as intersection of closed (normal reps.) sets.

For (b): I am trying to find a morphism of algebraic groups $G/H \to G_m \times \cdots \times G_m $ but I can't. Is there any other approach that will work.

But for the others I have no idea.

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: For b), show that $G/H$ is commutative and consists of semisimple elements. For c), there is a natural map. For d), prove that in the case $G = GL(n,K)$ we have $H = SL(n,K)$.